Is there a way to deal with EOFError: Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached
I am trying to process 80MB of data using ECS and the cpu and Memory has been configured with maximum configuration. I keep getting Error code 137 . so I decided to process my data in chunks but I keep getting this error
EOFError: Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker 

Is there a way I can fix this
import boto3
import gzip
import json


def process_file(input_file: str, output_file: str):
    
    input_bucket, input_key = split_s3_path(input_file)
    output_bucket, output_key = split_s3_path(output_file)

    s3 = boto3.client('s3')

    if 'SERVICE' in input_key:
        # Chunk size in bytes 
        chunk_size = 20 *1024 * 1024 

        response = s3.get_object(Bucket=input_bucket, Key=input_key)
        body = response['Body']
        part = 0
        while True:
            # Read a chunk of data
            chunk = body.read(chunk_size)

            # Break the loop if no more data
            if not chunk:
                break

            # Decompress the chunk
            decompressed_chunk = gzip.decompress(chunk)

            # Decode the decompressed data (assuming UTF-8 encoding)
            decoded_chunk = decompressed_chunk.decode('utf-8')

            # Process each line (JSON object) in the chunk
            json_data = []
            for line in decoded_chunk.split('\n'):
                # Skip empty lines
                if line.strip():
                    # Parse the JSON object
                    json_obj = json.loads(line)
                    json_data.append(json_obj)

            # Convert processed data to JSON string
            processed_data_str = '\n'.join(json.dumps(obj) for obj in json_data)

            # Compress the processed data
            compressed_content = gzip.compress(processed_data_str.encode('utf-8'))

            # Construct the key for the processed chunk
            outbound_key = f'{output_key}_part{part}.gz'

            # Upload the compressed content to S3
            s3.put_object(
                Bucket=output_bucket,
                Key=outbound_key,
                Body=compressed_content,
                ContentEncoding='gzip',
            )

            # Increment the part number for the next chunk
            part += 1

    else:
        if 'KING' in input_key:
            print("KING found")
        else:
            pass


Does gzip.decompress() support the concept of chunking?
